# Run file/function every X hours in android without open the app

Tags: java, android, cron

I want to know if there is a way to run a function or a file in my app when the app is close and not open in the background..

I'll explain, for example, in web development there is a thing called cronjobs which allows to run a file that stored on my server every time that as I setup even without open the actual website..

I want to know if there is something that allows my the same thing on android?

Comment: This is called service. A service will run in the background even if the app is closed.

Comment: What service? You can give me a link for a tutorial? @MirianaItani

Comment: I will give u an example

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if you need anymore assistance or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This class extends Service and in this class an image upload is done in the background even if the application is closed :

```
public class UploadPhotoService extends Service {
IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
String url;
//Notification n;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if(intent!=null) {
        if(intent.hasExtra("url")) {
    url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    int id = 1;
    // Issues the notification
    // here you do this if you want a service that constantly notifies the user of what is happening ( ex: music player)
    //n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Workee")
            .setContentText("Uploading Image")
            .setProgress(0, 0, true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.workee_logo).build();
    //startForeground(id, n);
    // execute the async task
    uploadPhoto();
    return START_STICKY;
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf(1);
}

public void uploadPhoto() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Server s = new Server(UploadPhotoService.this);
            return s.photoUpload(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
}
```

This is how you call a service :
Here I am calling the service from a fragment :

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadPhotoService.class);
        // I hvae the image path as an extra for the service to upload the image
        intent.putExtra("url", selectedImagePath);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
```

One more important thing, when you declare a service, it also has to be declared in the manifest as the following :

```
<service android:name=".services.UploadPhotoService" />
```